# Relative clause in the middle of the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

Is it good practice to embed a relative clause between the object and the second part of the verb.

> There will be a series of stories, that describe the backtesting process, published.

I guess the relative clause could be at the end of the sentence, but then it would follow the noun, it relates to.

> There will be a series of stories published, that describe the backtesting process.

Which one is more readable?

Comment: The simplest and best alternant would be "There will be a series of stories published that describe the backtesting process", in which the relative clause is postposed.  Note no comma with _that_ relatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These constructions are possible, but not ideal.

Firstly, you should get rid of the commas. These relative clauses should not be set off with commas.

Now, it is bad style to split the subject "stories" from the verb "published"  by too much modifying material.  It is also bad style to have a long phrase at the start of sentence. It is easy, in this case to avoid the problem. Either use an active sentence:

> They will publish a series of stories that describe the backtesting process.

or use two sentences:

> There will be a series of stories published. These stories will describe the backtesting process.

Using a participle phrase is also possible

> There will be a series of stories published describing the backtesting process.